# Why output contain 'D' in C# program of ReadKey()?

Tags: c#

In Output screen, When I press 2, then it prints D2.

### Why It prints D before output? I am using Visual studio 2019.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;

namespace CSharp5
{
    class Class3
    {
        static void Main()
        {
            ConsoleKeyInfo m = Console.ReadKey();
            Console.WriteLine("\n" + m.Key);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: That is the value of the Enum: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.keys?view=netframework-4.8

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because [Key](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.consolekeyinfo.key?view=netframework-4.8#System_ConsoleKeyInfo_Key) is used to determine which key has pressed.

If you press for example the <kbd>A</kbd> key you will get `'A'` in output **but** there are two <kbd>2</kbd> keys on a standard keyboard. One is on top of keyboard and other one is on number pad.

[Key](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.consolekeyinfo.key?view=netframework-4.8#System_ConsoleKeyInfo_Key) represents [Key Enum](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.keys?view=netframework-4.8), by this you are able to determine which <kbd>2</kbd> key has pressed.

If you press <kbd>2</kbd> on top of keyboard you will get `D2` in output.

If you press <kbd>2</kbd> on number pad you will get `NumPad2` in output.

If you need exact `'2'` on output use `KeyChar` instead of `key`.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{

    ConsoleKeyInfo m = Console.ReadKey();
    Console.WriteLine("\r\n Console key is:" + m.Key);
    Console.WriteLine("\r\n Unicode character is:" + m.KeyChar);
    Console.ReadKey();
}
```

Comment: Nice explained by Masoud Keshavarz. Thank you very much ! Also thanks you Jacob Lambert & Andy Lamb for your answer.

Answer (score 1):

You want the `KeyChar` property rather than `Key`.  `Key` is the enum representing the character and enum names (like other names in C#) can't start with a number. `KeyChar` is the unicode character representing the key pressed.